# React: 'p' is not defined no-undef in component file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react application wherein I want to render an array of menu items, and on click, show the expanded menu item's description. The array of menu items is in a separate file `dishes.js`

The list of menu items are rendered in a `Menu` component. On clicking, the expanded menu item is rendered through a `DishDetail` component.

**dishes.js**

```
export const DISHES =
[
    {...}
]
```

**MenuComponent.js**

```
class Menu extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props);
      this.state = {
        selectedDish: null
      } 
  }

  onDishSelect(dish){
      this.setState({ selectedDish: dish })
  }

  render() { 

    const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish)=>{
      return (

        <div key = {dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">    {/* why do we need this key attribute whenever we construct a list of items in react, we need this key attribute When rendering elements on screen, the keys help react identify these elements uniquely */}
          <Card onClick = {()=>this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
            <CardImg width="100%" src= {dish.image} alt = {dish.name} />
            <CardImgOverlay>
              <CardTitle> {dish.name} </CardTitle>
            </CardImgOverlay>
          </Card>
        </div>

      );

    });

    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">

            {menu} 

        </div>

        <div className = "row">

           <DishDetail p={this.state.selectedDish} />

        </div>

      </div>


    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

**DishdetailComponent.js**

```
class DishDetail extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  render() {
    if (p != null){

      return(
        <div className = "row">
          <Card>
            <CardImg width="100%" src={p.image} alt={p.name} />
            <CardBody>
              <CardTitle> {p.name} </CardTitle>
              <CardText> {p.description}</CardText>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>

        </div>
      );
    }

    else {
      return(
        <div> </div>
      );

    }
  }
}

export default DishDetail;
```

**Output**

```
./src/components/DishdetailComponent.js
  Line 17:9:   'p' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 22:40:  'p' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 22:54:  'p' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 24:28:  'p' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 25:27:  'p' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Properties are not magically injected into component scope. You need to read the p property from the component props. Add the following at the top of the DishdetailComponent render method `const { p } = this.props;`

Comment: Thanks a ton Robb! Makes total sense! Works like a charm now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not defining `p` in the render function. Did you perhaps mean `this.props.p`?

```
class DishDetail extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  render() {
    const { p } = this.props;

    if (p != null){

      return(
        <div className = "row">
          <Card>
            <CardImg width="100%" src={p.image} alt={p.name} />
            <CardBody>
              <CardTitle> {p.name} </CardTitle>
              <CardText> {p.description}</CardText>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>

        </div>
      );
    }

    else {
      return(
        <div> </div>
      );

    }
  }
}

export default DishDetail;
```

Comment: Thanks Franker! It works like a charm now, appreciate the help on this.